# order an array C# .NET

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of DICOM images and would like to sort by Z order (it's an attribute within the image)

here's my code for adding the images to the List

```
  private List<DicomImage> img = new List<DicomImage>();

   for (int i = 0; i < imagenes.Count; i++) //imagenes is a variable that holds the number of images (coming from an OpenFileDialog)
         {

            img.Add(new DicomImage(imagenes[i]));
          }
```

Now, how can I order ascending by Z?

Let's say Z attribute can be accessed simply by entering something like this:

int Z=img[i].Z;

Comment: Your existing code looks odd to me - are you sure you don't mean `i < imagenes.Count`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `imagenes` is some sort of `IEnumerable<T>`, I'd use LINQ for the whole thing:

```
var dicomImages = imagenes.Select(original => new DicomImage(original))
                          .OrderBy(image => image.Z)
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, so here's the Images list declaration:
  private List<DicomImage> img = new List<DicomImage>();
Then I do the for

Comment: @Matimont: This *replaces* `img` completely.

Comment: I changed the code in the original post, I had pasted it incorrectly

Comment: @Matimont: Okay, but you can still use the code in my answer to completely replace the code in your post.

Comment: Thanks! it worked this way:
    foreach (string filename in ofdmulti.FileNames)
    {
    img.Add(new DicomImage(filename)); // Llenar lista de imágenes.
                                           
                    }

                    var imgorder = from element in img
                                   orderby element.Dataset.Get<double>(Dicom.DicomTag.SliceLocation) descending
                                   select element;

Then:
  foreach (var element in imgorder)
                    {
    }

Comment: @Matimont: But why are you creating a list like that to start with using `Add`? You can do the whole thing in one query very simply.

Answer (score 0):

If img is a `List<T>`, you can use the [`Sort(Comparison<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method.

```
img.Sort((img1, img2) => img1.Z.CompareTo(img2.Z));
```

This just tells the sort method that when comparing two images, call this function that just reverts to comparing their Z values for the result.

Comment: @Matimont: Yeah, `Sort` just uses the function to compare two at a time.

Answer (score 0):

building on the comment to John skeets answer here's a more performant variant which saves on copying the images over

```
var dicomImages = ofdmulti.FileNames.Select(filename => new DicomImage(filename))
                                    .OrderBy(image => image.Z);

foreach (var image in dicomImages)
{
    // Do Something usefull
}
```